# Clicking a button in the webbroswer

Tags: c#

I know how to change the values as I have done it many times on several programs, I am confused on this error I continue to get...

---

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Destiny RedBull Code Generator By Rage.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

The code that is causing the error is as follows...

```
HtmlElement lenSeq = doc.GetElementById("lenSeq");
```

The entire code is...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

            HtmlElement lenSeq = doc.GetElementById("lenSeq");
            lenSeq.SetAttribute("value", "7".ToString());

            HtmlElement letters = doc.GetElementById("letters");
            letters.SetAttribute("value", "abcd".ToString());
        }

        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("Click to generate letter sequences");
            submit.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: That means that the 'doc' for what ever reason, is null.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You are clearly using another language apart from just html. If you edit your question and add a tag for that language, you are likely to get better help from people skilled in that language...

Comment: @bowlturner how can i fix that ? Also other programs I have created worked fine like this ?